# What does mailed-by in google means?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, sender-authentication-package

Hi can someone explain to me what does the "Mailed-By" in the email details in google mean?

And why is it that it says bounce.[subdomain].com on it.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a case, where the email seems to be sent from a Private Domain on SFMC, without an SAP being in place. In this case, the *mailed-by* is not masked.

Here is an example, where an SAP domain (link.adidas.com) is in place, and the email is sent from a Private Domain (dk-news.adidas.com):

[image]

Also, do keep in mind, that *signed-by* will not be masked by SAP/Private Domain when using shared IP for sending. Only dedicated IPs support this.

Answer (score 2):

Mailed by indicates what mail server an email is coming from.
Normal gmail - mail.google.com
'A company' using Gmail under Google for Organisations - acompany.com

Bounce simply means that this is an automatic email, not one sent by a human

Hope this helps!
MailNerd